# Substituir NULL por string

Tags: sql-server

Em um campo datetime, quando o valor for `NULL` deverá retornar apenas `-`, tentei a função `IFNULL`

```
SELECT ISNULL(data, '-') as data FROM tabela
```

porém me retorna o erro

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e07'

Falha ao converter data e/ou hora da cadeia de caracteres.
```

Comment: Marcelo, seria possível postar o seu código?

Comment: Editado, @Rubico

Comment: pelo que eu vi, você não está utilizando o ifnull, mas sim o isnull

Comment: @Rubico também tentei com ele. A solução comentada pelo Marconi solucionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resposta criada como Solicitado @Marcelo.

*Tente:*

```
 SELECT COALESCE(convert(varchar,DATA,103) + ' ' + SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,DATA,114),0,6), '-')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select COALESCE( CAST( DATA AS VARCHAR), '-') AS DATA from tabela
```

ou

```
select ISNULL( CAST( DATA AS VARCHAR ), '-') AS DATA from tabela
```

Comment: A solução proposta funcionou porém convertendo a data para o formato: `ABR 28 2016 10:07AM`. Há como deixar no padrão `28/04/2016 10:07` ?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade tenta `select COALESCE(  convert(varchar,DATA,103), '-') AS DATA from tabela`

Comment: Dessa forma ele retorna apenas a data `28/04/2016`, @Marconi

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade `COALESCE( convert(varchar,DATA,103) + ' ' +  SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,DATA,114),0,6), '-')`

Comment: Sim, desta forma funcionou corretamente @Marconi

Comment: @Marconi se puderes, cria uma resposta para que eu aceite.